# What does $^t X$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

This is a statement in the context of Linear Algebra:

[image]

Does anybody know that the $^t$ are? They are seen in the last term with $^t XY, \cdots,^tXA^{n-1}Y $.

If anybody could explain the notation I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Which book/paper? Page number? Section number?

Comment: It is from an extra question from a question sheet on second year Linear Algebra. This has never, to my knowledge, been used in lectures or in the rest of the sheet. I can provide the link if needed.

Comment: My guess is transpose. I could be deadly wrong.

Comment: For more context, I need to prove that this condition is the same as having a minimal polynomial of degree $n$. Would your suggestion make sense with that? Note that I don't want the answer, I just want to know if with this interpretation it makes sense.

Comment: To clarify, I meant the minimal polynomial for $A$.

Comment: ${}^tX$ means the transpose of $X$. I think it is mainly used by French linear algebra texts.

Comment: It denotes transposition. As a french guy this is how I used to write/see transposition before knowing this site and reading English books/papers.

Comment: Thank you! If one you could post this as an answer I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The notation is mentioned in the English wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose (and actively used in some parts of the article).

Comment: @user1551 do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: @ronno No, I would like French speakers to answer this question.